# Git-Bash: cannot execute command on mounted network folder

Tags: git-bash, mount

I want to run the following bash script using git-bash on Windows 10:

```
root_path=//my-synology-nas/exchange/myFolder

echo "Path to latest apk file"
cd $root_path 
ls  # <-- this line works
echo "Done"
apk_name=$(ls -t1 *.apk | head -1)  # <-- this is where the script hangs indefinitely
echo "$apk_name"
```

The same code works perfectly, when using any local path, eg

```
 root_path=/c/myFolder
 root_path=D:/myFolder  # both syntaxes work
```

I assume that the fact that I'm using a network drive is causing the issue. I already tried mapping the network drive to Z: but it doesn't help. Any idea? ( chatGPT doesn't know this one ;-P )